# How to sum objects in array by each id, count average sum, set in order with condition

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, underscore.js

I am using mongoose `find()` method to get all records from db. After that I want to create new sorted array or array of objects. Those record can have same parameter name like `"startNum"`. How can I have summed values with same parameter and counted average value of each?

I tried using Javascript for loops but I have got only arrays with this result values from db with this same `"startNum"` parameter, but few of them have empty spaces that I don't want - it's like `[2, , ,5]`. I think it can be done easier. It would be nice if it was made using underscorejs.

Here is my try:

```
stars.find({}, function(error, result) {
               if(error) {
                 console.log(error);
               }
               var tmp = {};
               var a = [];
               One = {};
               var snOne = [];
               Two = {};
               var snTwo = [];
               Three = {};
               var snThree = [];
               var Four = {};
               var snFour = [];
               var Five = {};
               var snFive = [];

              for (var s = 0; s < result.length; s ++) {
                if (result[s].startingNumber === 1) {
                  snOne[0] = 1; // numer startowy konia
                  snOne[s+1]=(result[s].categoryOne + result[s].categoryTwo + result[s].categoryThree + result[s].categoryFour + result[s].categoryFive);
                }


                 if (result[s].startingNumber === 2) {
                  for (var q = 0; q < result.length; q ++) {
                  snTwo[0] = 2;
                  snTwo[q+1]=(result[q].categoryOne + result[q].categoryTwo + result[q].categoryThree + result[q].categoryFour + result[q].categoryFive);
                  }
                }

              for (var w = 0; w < result.length; w ++) {
                 if (result[w].startingNumber === 3) {
                  snThree[0] = 3;
                  snThree[w+1]=(result[w].categoryOne + result[w].categoryTwo + result[w].categoryThree + result[w].categoryFour + result[w].categoryFive);
                }
              }
                for (var e = 0; e < result.length; e ++) {
                 if (result[e].startingNumber === 4) {
                  snFour[0] = 4;
                  snFour[e+1]=(result[e].categoryOne + result[e].categoryTwo + result[e].categoryThree + result[e].categoryFour + result[e].categoryFive);
                }
              }
                for (var r = 0; r < result.length; r ++) {
                 if (result[r].startingNumber === 5) {
                  snFive[0] = 5;
                  snFive[r+1]=(result[r].categoryOne + result[r].categoryTwo + result[r].categoryThree + result[r].categoryFour + result[r].categoryFive);
                }
              }
              }// ..
```

I know this sorting Underscore method, that can be useful, but dont know exactly how to do this.

```
var sorted = _.sortBy(a, function(num) { return num; });
```

To sum up I want to have counted average value for each `startingNum` category. For example array of objects

**first object**

```
{
    startingNum: 1,
counted_Average_Of_All_Existing_In_DataBase_Categories_From_One_To_Five_For_startingNum1: value
}
```

Those mongoose results looks like:

```
[ {
categoryFive: 1,
categoryFour: 1,
categoryThree: 1,
categoryTwo: 1,
categoryOne: 1,
startingNumber: 1},... ]
```

I think it would be much better using `underscorejs`. Can someone help? I can't figure out how to make it right.

Comment: please add some more data of the array.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could edit your question to include some sample documents and the expected result documents because it's hard to follow what you are trying to do as it currently stands.

Comment: @NinaScholz I hope it's better described http://pastebin.com/CsLZ98gG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you have already written javascript loop code to group your documents by startingNumber and then sum the category values, and you just wanted input on how best to sort that using underscore.js.

However, I believe it would be better and simpler to use MongoDB's aggregation framework to do the grouping, summing and sorting for you. You had also said you wanted a *counted average* so my sample code calculates count and average too.

If I load your sample data:

```
db.catdata.insert([
  {categoryFive:   1, categoryFour:   1, categoryThree:   1, 
   categoryTwo:    1, categoryOne:    1, startingNumber:  1},
  {categoryFive:   2, categoryFour:   1, categoryThree:   2, 
   categoryTwo:    1, categoryOne:    2, startingNumber:  1},
  {categoryFive:   1, categoryFour:   1, categoryThree:   1, 
   categoryTwo:    1, categoryOne:    1, startingNumber:  2},
  {categoryFive:  20, categoryFour:   1, categoryThree:  20, 
   categoryTwo:   20, categoryOne:   20, startingNumber:  1},
  {categoryFive: 100, categoryFour: 100, categoryThree: 100, 
   categoryTwo:  100, categoryOne:  100, startingNumber:  2}
]) ;
```

then this statement:

```
db.catdata.aggregate([
    {"$project" : {"startingNumber":1,
           "cats1to5":{$add:["$categoryFive", "$categoryFour", 
           "$categoryThree", "$categoryTwo",  "$categoryOne"]}
                  }
    }
   ,{"$group": {"_id"  : "$startingNumber",  "cntCat":{$sum:1},
                "totCat":{$sum:"$cats1to5"}, "avgCat":{$avg:"$cats1to5"}
               }
    }
   ,{$sort : {startingNumber:1}}
]);
```

produces this output:

```
{ "_id" : 2, "cntCat" : 2, "totCat" : 505, "avgCat" : 252.5 }
{ "_id" : 1, "cntCat" : 3, "totCat" : 94, "avgCat" : 31.333333333333332 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you wanted to find the total score across all categories grouped by the starting number. If so, here goes the solution using [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/)

```
// group by startingNumber
// each group will have multiple objects denoted by 'objs'
var grouped = _.chain(data).groupBy('startingNumber').map(function (objs, startNum) {
    // iterate through the objects for the current starting number
    var score = _.chain(objs).map(function (obj) {
        // remove all keys which are not starting with category
        var obj    = _.pick(obj, function (value, key) {
            return key.indexOf('category') !== -1;
        });
        var scores = _.values(obj); // get the scores for each category

        // compute the sum across all categories for this object
        return _.reduce(scores, function (memo, categoryScore) {
            return memo + categoryScore;
        }, 0);
        // compute the sum across all objects for this group
    }).reduce(function (memo, value) {
        return memo + value;
    }, 0).value();

    return {
        start: startNum,
        score: score
    };
}).value();
```